# How can I disable warnings in Android Studio using Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Basically due to Nullsafety migration there are a bunch of warnings that also are error-red coloured and make actual errors hide with the bunch. So my question:

How can I disable the showing of warnings in Android Studio with Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant disable showing of warnings cause android studio had'nt added a plugin or button to hide and unhide it , The way to do this is to solve warnings :(

Comment: ouch, but oh well. I'll wait maybe someone else knows something, if not I'll accept your answer

Comment: thank you Maritn Ge ı hopefully you'll find answers :)